# Install gcc on linux with no root privilege

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I have access to computer in a public library and I want to try out some C++ and maybe other code. Problem is that there is no g++ installed and I can't install it using packages because I have no root access. Is there a "smart" way to make a full environment for programming in a home folder?

I have gcc installed (I can compile C code). Also, I have a home folder that is consistent. I don't know where to find precompiled g++, I found only source but I don't know what to do with it. I tried to ask them to install this but it didn't work :)

Comment: Does the library have gcc installed?

Comment: I can compile C source using gcc.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to install it as a local user

GNU GSRC provides an easy way to do so

Link: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/

After configuration, simply specify the following commands:

```
cd gsrc
make -C pkg/gnu/gcc 
make -C pkg/gnu/gcc install
```

The second step could also be changed to speed up for an N-core system:

```
make -C pkg/gnu/gcc MAKE_ARGS_PARALLEL="-jN"
```

Comment: I do recommend a stable release (like 2013.07) instead of the trunk, download from: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsrc/

Comment: Will this also install a new version of standard lib c++?

Answer (score 11):

You can run the configure script with the --prefix parameter: `../gcc-4.5.0/configure --prefix=/home/foo/bar`. Since it is very likely that the c++ standard library is different then the one on your system, you have to set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/foo/bar/lib` before you can start a program compiled by this compiler.

Comment: That is dependent on there being an existing compiler toolchain to bootstrap from.

Comment: I tried ./configure --prefix=... but it gives me:  

configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."

Comment: It seems that you are trying to do the build inside the source tree. This is unsupported by the gcc maintainers, they want the build to be in a directory next to the gcc sources. Also, which packages did you unpack? You need both the `gcc-core` and `gcc-g++` to generate the c++ compiler (or the complete[=largest] package). The missing `install-sh` is in the gcc-core package.

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/ may be useful for how-to get g++ building.

Comment: You actually need to do this before building GCC if you are using your own versions of GMP, MPC, MPFR and ISL because GCC uses those shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Once, a long time ago (1992 or so), I went through something similar to this when I bought a SCO system with no development environment.  Bootstrapping it up to having a full development environment was a gigantic pain, and not at all easy.  Having library header files or gcc on a system would make your job a whole lot easier.

It depends a lot on just how obnoxious the library has been about what kinds of things are installed.  If there is no `gcc` there, your job becomes a bit harder.  If there are no header files for glibc there, your job is a LOT harder.

Also, do you get an account on the system so you have a home folder that's consistent from login to login?

If you have no `gcc` there, you need to find a pre-compiled binary of gcc/g++ and install it somewhere.  If you have no header files there, you need to find copies of those and put them on the system.

There is no 'standard' way of installing gcc in your home folder though.  All of the solutions are going to have some manner of hand-rolling involved.

Have you asked the librarians if they can change what's installed because you want to learn a bit of programming and only have access to their computers to do it with?  That might well be the easiest solution.

From your comment it seems that you do have `gcc` and if you can compile C code, you have the library header files.  So now it's a matter of actually compiling your own version of `g++`.  You could probably find a way to entice the package manager on the system into installing a binary package somewhere other than in a system folder.  I think this solution is less fun than compiling your own, and I think there may also be possible subtle problems as that installed package may be expecting to find things in particular places and not finding them there.

First thing to do is to make sure you've downloaded the right source for the gcc package.  The place to find that is the [GNU United States mirror page](http://www.gnu.org/prep/ftp.html).  You want to find the `gcc-4.5.0.tar.bz2` or `gcc-4.5.0.tar.gz` file on the mirror site you choose.  It will likely be in a `gcc` directory, and a `gcc-4.5.0` sub-folder.

After you have that downloaded, you should untar it.  In general you shouldn't build gcc in the folder you untar it into.  So create another sibling folder that you actually want to build it in labeled `gcc-build`.  Then the command you want is `../gcc-4.5.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/.local --enable-languages='c c++'`.

gcc does require some other packages be installed in order to be able to compile itself.  You can use the same `--prefix` line for these packages to install them in the same place.  The gcc website has a [list of pre-requisite packages](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html).

`$HOME/.local` is sort of the standard accepted place for per-user installs of things.

Comment: I have gcc installed (I can compile C code). Also, I have a home folder that is consistent. I don't know where to find precompiled g++, I found only source but I don't know what to do with it. I tried to ask them to install this but it didn't work :)

Comment: @user287655 - I will add this comment to your question so as to further clarify it.

Comment: But don't try to build a new version of GCC.  According to https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html GCC needs a C++98 compiler unless you are building GCC prior to 4.8 which allow bootstrapping with a C89 compiler

Answer (score 0):

If you have fakeroot, you can use that to set ~/some-path as root to install the packages from. Alternatively, you can setup a chroot environment to do the same.

Given this, you can then use `dpkg -i package.deb` to install the gcc package(s) on your system. You will need to download and install each package individually (e.g. from the debian website) -- at least `binutils`, `glibc`, `linux-headers` and `gcc`.

If you are on another system, you will need to get the right packages for that system and install them using the corresponding package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you need gcc for installing a python package, maybe try the following before installing it:

```
conda install gcc gxx_linux-64
```