# Permission denied when trying to install gcc, even if logged as root

Tags: gcc, makefile, installation, root, permission-denied

I'm trying to install gcc 4.7.0 on ubuntu 10.04 following that tutorial http://www.tellurian.com.au/whitepapers/multiplegcc.php. After some time to install the dependencies, I've been able to run make without errors, but the final step, make install doesn't want to succeed, it end up with permission denied.

Here's what I did :

```
../gcc-4.7.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc/4.7.7 --enable-languages=c,c++
make
su -l
cd /groups/gobj
make install
```

the result for the last command :

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/groups/gobj'
/bin/bash ../gcc-4.7.0/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7 /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7
make[2]: Entering directory `/groups/gobj/fixincludes' 
rm -rf /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/install-tools
/bin/bash ../../gcc-4.7.0/fixincludes/../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/libexec
...
rm -f /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/share/info/gccinstall.info
if [ -f doc/gccinstall.info ]; then \
      for f in doc/gccinstall.info*; do \
        realfile=`echo $f | sed -e 's|.*/\([^/]*\)$|\1|'`; \
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $f /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/share/info/$realfile; \
        chmod a-x /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/share/info/$realfile; \
      done; \
    else true; fi
if /bin/bash -c 'install-info --version' >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
      if [ -f /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/share/info/gccinstall.info ]; then \
        install-info --dir-file=/usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/share/info/dir /usr/local/gcc/4.7.7/share/info/gccinstall.info; \
      else true; fi; \
    else true; fi;
build/genhooks -d \
                    ../../gcc-4.7.0/gcc/doc/tm.texi.in > tmp-tm.texi
/bin/bash: tmp-tm.texi: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [s-tm-texi] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/groups/gobj/gcc'
make[1]: *** [install-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/groups/gobj'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I've already tried su root, su -, su without succes. Some files are effectively copied to /usr/local/gcc/4.7.0 but the process stopped and I don't understand why as I'm logged as root. I've checked, the file /groups/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/doc/tm.texi.in exists. Any help ?

Comment: What are the permissions of `/groups/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/doc/tmp-tm.texi` or   `/groups/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/doc/`?

Comment: /groups/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/doc/tmp-tm.texi doesn't exist and /groups/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/doc/ : drwxr-xr-x  3 laurencew users   10240 2012-03-22 09:30 doc

Comment: I've managed to install it in a subdirectory of /groups but would like to understand what's going on with the installation in /usr/local

Comment: Something is wrong about `tmp-tm.texi`. It might be that `build/genhooks` expects it to be there. I would either `make distclean` and rebuild, or if that doesn't work build without the docs (check the `configure` flag).

Comment: I don't think the build is problematic as I've been able to install it in /groups and I've used make distclean before that build (as with all previous failed attempts result in Bootstrap comparison failure the time before).

Comment: Yes, the build is problematic since it e.g. fails.

Comment: I think it doesn't fail as I've been able to install it in a different folder and have just been able to use gcc-4.7.0 to compile a library with it

Answer (score 2):

As puzzling as it sounds that the superuser "root" cannot create files while a normal user can, a likely scenario is that your build directory (that is, the directory in which you ran "`make install`") is being served from an NFS server, and it is probably mounted such that the server doesn't trust your build machine's request to write files as root.

As a simple test see if you can write an empty file to the build directory by running `touch test` as root. If that fails then you've found the source of the problem. Another way to confirm it is to check the output of "`mount`" at at least confirm that your build directory is being served via NFS.

```
server:/groups      20G  948M   19G   5% /groups
```

If you see a line like this in the mount output then you know for certain that your build directory is being NFS mounted. To tell whether or not root is being trusted, however, you'll ultimately have to check the settings on the NFS server.

## Fixing the problem

The fastest way to fix this issue is to find a local filesystem on your build machine and move the contents of your build directory there, then re-run "`make install`".

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried sudo?

```
sudo make install
```

Edit:

As root, you can add yourself to sudoers.
If you can't get root via sudo, try either

```
su - root
```

or

```
ssh root@...
```

Comment: Have you tried sudo -i; cd'ing to the install directory; and then running make install? If not, what are the errors? You can edit your original post to add the errors.

Comment: sorry, previous comment is wrong. I can't use sudo with my account because my account is not in the sudoer group. But I've got the root's password of my computer

Comment: Thanks Juri, but it's not my personnal computer, I'm doing an internship in a company. I can't add my user to the sudoer group. Everything I read on that subject is usually resolved when logged under root and it's what I've been doing. I don't understand why it is not working in my case ?

Comment: If only you are supposed to use the gcc, consider compiling the gcc to your home directory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212099/install-gcc-on-linux-with-no-root-privilege

Comment: That's kind of what I've been doing (not in /home but a different folder) and it works, but I would really understand why I'm not able as root to install it in /usr/local. Otherwise my problem is solved.