# After checking the related posts, still cannot install GCC 4.7 on Linux without root privilege?

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, g++, permission-denied

After checking the posts:

[Install gcc on linux with no root privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212099/install-gcc-on-linux-with-no-root-privilege)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316118/installing-gcc-as-non-root

My problem still cannot be solved so I post it here.

I am trying to install GCC 4.7 on Linux with gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52).

I run configure with prefix to be my home directory.

```
./configure \
    --with-gmp=/remote/home/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/gmp505 \
    --with-mpfr=/remote/home/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/mpfr242 \
    --with-mpc=/remote/home/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/mpc081 \
    --disable-libjava
```

Then, make is ok. But, make check is not ok, I got error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/remote/home/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/trunk'

make[2]: Entering directory `/remote/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/trunk/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes'

autogen -T ../.././fixincludes/check.tpl ../.././fixincludes/inclhack.def

make[2]: execvp: autogen: Permission denied

make install is not ok. 

make[1]: Entering directory `/remote/home/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/trunk'
/bin/sh ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local /usr/local

make[2]: Entering directory `/remote/home/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/trunk/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes'

rm -rf /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/install-tools
/bin/sh ../.././fixincludes/../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/install-tools

mkdir -p -- /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/install-tools

mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/libexec/gcc': Permission denied
```

I cannot get root privilege.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: You don't seem to have a `--prefix` argument when running configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling GCC, you should **never build it in its source tree**!

You forgot a prefix in your configure arguments, perhaps something like

```
mkdir $HOME/gcc-build
cd $HOME/gcc-build
/your/path/to-source-tree/gcc-4.7.0/configure --prefix $HOME/pref \
         --program-suffix -my4.7 \
# other configure arguments go here
```

of course, you'll find your compiler installed in `$HOME/pref/bin/gcc-my4.7` so I recommend adding `$HOME/pref/bin` to your `$PATH` and `$HOME/pref/lib` to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

You might try to build the GCC [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) [meta-] plugin once you installed successfully your GCC 4.7

<sup>The `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` mailing list is a good place to get such help.</sup>

Comment: Thanks ! I got new errors: configure: error: building out of tree but /remote/mypath/gcc_4_7_2012_5_28/trunk contains host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu. Use a pristine source tree when building in a separate tree. I have to remove host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu ? thanks !

Comment: gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org does not work even though I have subscribed to it. So, I still get building errors even though I built it in another directory with correct prefix: checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/remote/mypath/gcc_4_7_build_2012_5_28/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc': configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile , See `config.log' for more details. make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1  ,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the config.log file, look for the "checking for suffix of object files". You should see an error message somewhere near there which should help you out.

Or, use EasyBuild for building GCC 4.7, which does everything for you, see http://hpcugent.github.com/easybuild.