# C++11 compatible compiler on linux server without root access?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, clang

What is the easiest route to installing a c++11 compatible compiler on a linux web server without root (sudo) access? The current gcc version is `g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313`. I've already tried:

- building modern gcc versions from scratch (e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC). This inevitably fails during `make` with an error like:

`` cp: cannot stat `libgcc_s.so.1': No such file or directory" ``

- building modern clang/llvm from scratch. This seems to compile correctly and the binaries can compile very simple programs. But fails to compile programs using many stdlib classes or routines.

Is there a bullet-proof (or *fool*-proof) way to build a working compiler from scratch?

Or, even better, is there a way to install compiler binaries and standard libraries without root access?

Comment: which Linux distribution?

Comment: Check this [install gcc on linux with no root privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212099/install-gcc-on-linux-with-no-root-privilege)

Comment: Install gcc somewhere that doesn't require root access.

Comment: You could make a chroot environment in your user space. Either that or just make sure you have your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and dynamic linker set properly when compiling.

Comment: Seems you compiled `clang` fine, but you lack a c++11 standard library to link against. So download one, and compile and install that too. Then recompile `clang` configured to use the c++11 standard library by default.

Comment: @jxh, I tried this http://libcxx.llvm.org/ but eventually it wants me to have gcc >=4.7

Comment: Sam Miller, Redhat Centos.

Comment: You need to bootstrap the compilation of the c++11 library with the version of `clang` you got compiled then.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 different questions in your one question:

**Question 1**: Which version of GCC fully supports C11.

**Answer 1**: As I know full C11 support comes with GCC 4.7.3 or later.

**Question 2**: Where is my libgcc_s.so.1 or any libgcc*.so*

**Answer 2**: It is compiler installation problem and is distribution dependend. For example mine is at "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.3/".If you are using package based distro - look for the package owns libgcc. Every distribution must provide the search tool that let you find which package owns(includes) the library.

**Question 3**: Do i need root privilleges to compile "hello world"?

**Answer 3**: Quickly - no, you should not or check you installation state. May be some one played with chmod?

**Question 4**: Where to get working GCC-4.7.3 or higher?

**Answer 4**: In repository depends on your distribution. Debian and Ubuntu using apt-get, RPM based distros sticking with rpm and yum. My lovely gentoo has eix/emerge magic. Slackware and friends are using own *.TGZ format.

Administration tasks without root access usually are not possible but check if you could sudo. I suppose that you are using a flavour of Ubuntu. If so - use sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Several $dayjob$ ago, one of the tasks were to set up an enterprise-wide development platform, installed on a network filesystem, offering multiple versions of gcc on multiple versions.

Building gcc manually is certainly possible. But it is **hard**.

It took several experienced hackers to figure out how to bootstrap gcc. It was a team effort. One thing that may not be very obvious is that different versions of `gcc` often have very subtle dependencies on specific versions of `binutils`, so, first and foremost, you need to bootstrap `binutils`, and only *then* try to build gcc. And, bootstrapping `binutils` is itself a somewhat of a shot in the dark; it's not very obvious whether the end product actually works, since, well, before the new compiler gets built, there's very little that can be done to test various bits of it.

Then, after finally getting gcc built, you get to discover all the mysterious assumptions but not just gcc, but ld, from binutils, has about where the standard C library, and gcc's own libstdc++ gets installed, and how to twiddle gcc's not-very documented configuration file, to tweak the library paths in *just* the right way.