# GCC local installation Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, gcc4.7

I have access to public machine which don't provide sudo access. How can I install latest g++ in a local folder in Ubuntu and use it while compiling and running C++ programs?
I tried this solution ([Install gcc on linux with no root privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212099/install-gcc-on-linux-with-no-root-privilege)) but its not working.

it Produces Error  bzr: ERROR: Connection error: failed to connect to bzr.savannah.gnu.org:4155: Connection refused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install gcc on linux with no root privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212099/install-gcc-on-linux-with-no-root-privilege)

Comment: After what step are you getting the bzr error?

Comment: @jelmer in the command 'bzr checkout bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/gsrc/trunk/ gsrc' I am getting bzr error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your network does not allow connections to most TCP/IP ports. Bazaar uses TCP/IP port (port 4155). On my network this works fine:

```
% bzr branch bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/gsrc/trunk/ /tmp/gsrc
Branched 3509 revisions.
```

Comment: I tried this but still not worked. produced error  'Cloning into 'gsrc'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.savannah.gnu.org:
git.savannah.gnu.org[0: 208.118.235.72]: errno=Connection refused'

Comment: Your network appears to be refusing connections to the custom bazaar or git ports (4155, 3169). I have updated the answer.