# how to install g++ in hpc compute node

Tags: c++, g++

I have given access to HPC node. I want to run script which compile and execute c++ code.

It gives me error which I described here:

[Slurm script.sh file to compile and run c++ error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931093/slurm-script-sh-file-to-compile-and-run-c-error)

On of the answers is that g++ is not installed. How can I install g++ in HPC cluster?

Should I be a root user to install?

Many thanks,

Comment: Relevant: [Install gcc on linux with no root privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3212099/580083)

Comment: It would be very odd that it's not installed, since it's needed for even basic functionality of that cluster (I imagine). More likely you are using the wrong alias or not loading the right module. Are there any help/doc pages for the cluster you are using? This type of information should be there. If not, I would contact the administrator.